# crear un input type range circular

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy intentando hacer un input de tipo range que sea circular, similar a esto:
[image]

pero lo unico que encuentro son progress bar circulares, y yo necesito un input range que sea circular y que se pueda cambiar el valor, y darle un valor minimo y uno maximo a gusto
los mas parecidos que encontre en cuanto a funcionamiento son estos:
[1](https://codepen.io/skyajay/pen/raGGLe) y [2](https://codepen.io/long-lazuli/pen/NPEPyM)
pero ninguno de los dos me convence, estaria buscando algo como el de arriba, alguien tiene alguna idea? el valor luego tendria que mandarlo en un formulario con el metodo post, ayuda porfavor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con este [plugin](https://jquerywp.com/roundslider-circular-jquery-range-slider) que está hecho con jQuery.